# Display each div related to their link JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

```js
$(".inline-title a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
   var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
   $(".documents").hide();
   $("." + selector).show();
   $('.inline-title a:first-child').removeClass('active');
   $(".inline-title .active").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-title">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="wcpf-test-1" class="active">This is the first test</a>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="wcpf-test-2">The second one is here !</a>
</div>

<div class="documents wcpf-test-1">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>

<div class="documents wcpf-test-2">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

WHat I want is

First my divs are not displayed in the pages

WHen you click on the first link with `data-toggle="wpcf-test-1"`, the following div with the class `wpcf-test-1` appears.

Then if you click on the seconf link with `data-toggle="wpcf-test-2"`, the following div with the class `wpcf-test-2` appears and the other disappear.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Very well! What have you tried so far?

Comment: So you want your paragraphs to be hidden until it's div is clicked (/opened)?

Comment: Yes this is what I need

Answer (score 0):

this can work for you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("a").on("click",function(){
       var classname = $(this).data("toggle");
        $("div.documents").hide();
        $(this).next("div."+classname).slideToggle("400");
     })
});
```

Comment: Use `var` and not create globals!

Comment: this is not hiding the current div displayed ?

Comment: @MeeneshJain are you sure ?

Comment: @MeeneshJain sure , you corrected your typo on `document` .

Comment: @Hacketo yes i did, it was a mistake in copy paste, sorry for that, is my answer well enough ? or any improvements i need to do in it

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".documents").hide(); // Hide other .documents div
    $(this).next().show();  // Display the one next to the `a` clicked
});
```

```css
.documents{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" data-toggle="wcpf-test-1">This is the first test</a>
<div class="documents wcpf-test-1">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="wcpf-test-2">The second one is here !</a>
<div class="documents wcpf-test-2">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.documents').hide();
  $('a[data-toggle]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.documents').hide();
    var selector = $(this).data('toggle');
    $('.'+selector).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="wcpf-test-1">This is the first test</a>
<div class="documents wcpf-test-1">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="wcpf-test-2">The second one is here !</a>
<div class="documents wcpf-test-2">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

So, the script first hides all the `div.documents`.

Then I've added a trigger on every anchor that has a `data-toggle` attribute. On a click all the `div.documents` get hidden, and next the div corresponding the `data-toggle` gets shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('a[data-toggle]').on('click', function(){
    $('div.' + $(this).data('toggle')).toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: this is not hiding the current div displayed ?

Comment: @CY5 the `toggle` event and `toggle` function are completely different things

Answer (score 0):

This will work as expected:

JQUERY:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $('div.documents').hide();
    var elem = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
    $('div.' + elem).show();
});
```

CSS:

```
.documents {display: none;}
```